# How do I see/get the Number of subreddits I downloaded using reddits API

Tags: python, json, api, reddit

```
>>> import requests
>>> from pprint import pprint 

>>> r = requests.get('http://www.reddit.com/reddits.json', headers= {'User-Agent': 'me'})
>>> data = r.json()
>>> pprint(data.keys())
```

This prints subreddits & im trying to figure out how much it prints out or if I can print out a certain number. Thanks !

Comment: `how much it prints out` try it maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.reddit.com/reddits.json', headers= {'User-Agent': 'me'})
data = r.json()

print(len(data['data']['children']))
```

The structure of the JSON is complicated, so I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to count, but `['data']['children']` appears to be the root of the subreddits.

Comment: why it returns , user_subscriber_status = null ?